# How to debug issues detecting AddIns when using MAF FindAddIns method?

Tags: c#, .net, maf

Is anyone able to provide a reliable method of debugging issues with detecting plugins when using MAF (using the [FindAddIns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addinstore.findaddins(v=vs.110).aspx) method)?

It seems that sometimes when I build my project and run a unit test it does not detect the plugin(s) in the designated folder.

Comment: Are you rebuilding the pipeline after every build or as part of your running application?  The [Rebuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470552(v=vs.110).aspx) method sometimes returns an error message that is more usable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @JohnKoerner. I'm actually using the [Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355338(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Not sure how the 2 methods differ, sounds like they do the same thing from the docs! I'm not sure what the problem was but it seems to be working now (the `Update` method was returning no errors).